# Need help adding up a score from correct answers taken from <input> in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and I made a sort of quiz thingy that has 10  input areas on a page. Using javascript I want to be able to verify the typed answer and give a point for correct and no point for incorrect.

html:

```
<div>
        <h1>Postal knowledge test. Write all the answers in lowercase, no spaces!</h1><br><br>
        <h5>Who do you play as in Postal 2?</h5><br>
        <input type="text" id="maincharacter"><br>
        <h5>Who is the voice actor for the character you play as?</h5><br>
        <input type="text" id="voiceactor"><br>
        <h5>How many days are there in Postal 2?</h5><br>
        <input type="number" id="days"><br>
        <h5>What do you need to retrieve from the Factory?</h5><br>
        <input type="text" id="factory"><br>
        <h5>On what day do you need to piss on your dads grave?</h5><br>
        <input type="text" id="dadgrave"><br>
        <h5>What weapon spawns in the shed in front of you on Monday?</h5><br>
        <input type="text" id="weapon"><br>
        <h5>What female animal is the wife named after?</h5><br>
        <input type="text" id="wife"><br>
        <h5>What's uncles name?</h5><br>
        <input type="text" id="uncle"><br>
        <h5>What item gives you 125 health?</h5><br>
        <input type="text" id="health"><br>
        <h5>How many official Postal games are there?</h5><br>
        <input type="number" id="games"><br><br>
        <button id="checkanswers" type="button" onclick="answer()">Check how many questions you got correct</button><br>
        <h5 id="answer"></h5>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
function answer() {
                const q1 = document.getElementById("maincharacter");
                let qq1 = q1.value;
                const q2 = document.getElementById("voiceactor");
                let qq2 = q1.value;
                const q3 = document.getElementById("days");
                let qq3 = q1.valueAsNumber;
                const q4 = document.getElementById("factory");
                let qq4 = q1.value;
                const q5 = document.getElementById("dadgrave");
                let qq5 = q1.value;
                const q6 = document.getElementById("weapon");
                let qq6 = q1.value;
                const q7 = document.getElementById("wife");
                let qq7 = q1.value;
                const q8 = document.getElementById("uncle");
                let qq8 = q1.value;
                const q9 = document.getElementById("health");
                let qq9 = q1.value;
                const q10 = document.getElementById("games");
                let qq10 = q1.valueAsNumber;
            }
```

What my original plan was, was to check the answer using an if statement i.e.:

```
//first question checker
var p1;

if (qq1 == "postaldude") {
    p1 = 1;
}
else {
    p1 = 0;
}

document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = p1;
```

p1 being given the value 1 or 0 depending if the answer is correct or not, then being added up with the other question results in the innerHTML i.e.: p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5... ;

but this doesn't work as you can't have more than 1 if statement, so if I try to add more of these it simply doesn't work. I tried using else if but I can't get it to work.

I am unsure if there is a way to what I'm trying to do work or if there is a fully different method of doing it. Sorry if my code is very basic, this is what I've learned so far. Anyhow any tips or explanation would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

What I tried:

I tried adding 10 if else statements for each question i.e.:

```
if (...) {
    ...;
}
else {
    ...;
}
if (...) {
    ...;
}
else {
    ...;
}
if (...) {
    ...;
}
else {
    ...;
}
if (...) {
    ...;
}
else {
    ...;
}
...
```

but unsurprisingly that didn't work. I also tried doing what I did above but making them all 'else if' but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

First, add a class to each of the inputs so you can simplify the checking.

E.G `<input type="text" class="question" id="maincharacter">`

Now, javascript canlook like this. Where `answer_sheet` will have a key for each input matching the ID.

```
// Select all elements with class 'question' and assign them to the variable 'questions'
const questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question");

// Define a constant object 'answer_sheet' containing key-value pairs of questions and answers
const answer_sheet = { 
    "maincharacter": "postaldude"
};

function answer() { 
    // Initialize score to 0
    var score = 0;
    
    // Iterate through each question element
    questions.forEach((question) => { 

        // Check if the question id exists in the answer sheet
        if(!(question.id in answer_sheet)) return;
        
        // Store the value of question in lowercase
        var questionValue = question.value.toLowerCase();

        // Store the value of answer in lowercase
        var answerValue = answer_sheet[question.id].toLowerCase();
        
        // Compare the question value and answer value
        if(questionValue == answerValue) {

            // if they match increase the score
            score++;
        }
    });

    // Show the score using an alert
    alert("Score: " + score);
}
```

Please note that anyone can inspect the code on the page and see the answer sheet as given, so this isn't very secure.

To get around this, you would probably utilize a technology like Ajax to send a list of the answers the user provided to a separate PHP script to process the answers, but it's a bit out of scope of your question.

Comment: And instead of requiring them to enter in all lower case you can use **((question.value.toLowerCase() == answer_sheet[question.id].toLowerCase()**. This will allow them to enter in any case that they want.

Comment: Yup that worked greatly thanks you so much! I had no clue you could a 'answer_sheet' that holds values for given IDs. I appreciate your help tremendously thank you!

Comment: @pentol This is just called an Object in Javascript. Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

### Hi

There is no problem in adding multiple if statements, but you can do the same in a scalable way.

1. Save question input ids and answers in an object (you can use `Map` also)

```
const idAnswersMap = {
"maincharacter": "postaldude",
"voiceactor": "answer"
}
```

2. checkout `for-in` loop for looping through objects
3. get answer for each input, compare with actual answer and sum in the same loop
4. Don't ever forget to name variables based on their use, it will help you afterwards big time.

```
let totalCorrect = 0;
for (let id in idAnswersMap) {
    // get answer for each input
    const answer = document.getElementById(id).value;
    if (answer === idAnswersMap[id]) {
      totalCorrect++;
    }
}
```

5. `totalCorrect` now holds what you need.

Comment: I like that this answer uses `let` and `const` instead of `var`, a `===` instead of `==`, and doesn't require a "question" class on every input element. It might be a good idea to `.toLowerCase()` the answer key and user-submitted answers though if the answers aren't case-sensitive. You will also throw an error in the console while trying to access `.value` on a null element if the answer key has an id that isn't found as an input element id.